# How to tell a user its not their turn when clicking button interaction discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, discord-buttons

this is what i have, a simple filter that filters the user that should be allowed inside the component collector.
this is what i would logically do, check if the ids arent equal, but how can i do it when the filter only allows the user id in?

and if i pass both ids in the filter, it will allow both users to click when it isnt their turn.

any answers would be helpful! thanks

```
const filter = (button) => {
          button.deferUpdate()
          return button.user.id === info.userid;
}
collector.on('collect', b => {
if (b.user.id !== info.userid) //reply and tell them its not their turn
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can send a message to the user with the ephemeral property. Only them will be able to see the message.

[discord.js: ButtonInteraction.reply()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ButtonInteraction?scrollTo=reply)

For example:

```
collector.on('collect', b => {
    if (b.user.id !== info.userid) {
        b.reply({content: "It's not your turn", ephemeral: true})
    }
}
```